# Error in await _context: "cannot reference a type through an expression"

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, razor-pages

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018401/ilist-returning-count-0-on-posting-back-updated-checkboxes)

I've edited my .cs like this:

```
private readonly GroupAccessDetailsModel _context;
public GroupAccessDetailsModel(GroupAccessDetailsModel context)
{
    _context = context;
}
[BindProperty]
public IList<OutputAccessRights> UsersAccessRights { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    UsersAccessRights = await _context.OutputAccessRights.ToListAsync();

    if (UsersAccessRights == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Model:

```
 public class OutputAccessRights
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool ChkUserAccessRights { get; set; }
    public string SubMenuDescription { get; set; }
    public string MainMenuDescription { get; set; }
    public bool ChkAddRight { get; set; }
}
```

But my problem is in await _context.**OutputAccessRights**.ToListAsync().

Error: *cannot reference a type through an expression*.

I've tried replacing it with await _context.GroupAccessDetailsModel.OutputAccessRights.ToListAsync(); but it didn't work. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: cannot reference a type through an expression.

That is because you use a model instead of using a DbContext.

You need first learn how to use [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/):

Then you could follow the tutorial about [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The following code in `OnGet` method is used to display all the `OutputAccessRights` data.

```
UsersAccessRights = await _context.OutputAccessRights.ToListAsync();
```

The previous thread's issue is not able to pass the select checkbox list.It means you could display the data,but could not pass the select checkbox to `OnPost`.

What I did for `Edit.cshtml.cs` is to test the `OnPost` method whether it could get the list checkbox or not.No need to care about how do I set `OutputAccessRights` on `OnGet` method,just use your previous code on `OnGet` method.

Here is the whole code about how to use EF Core:

1.DbContext(`_context.OutputAccessRights` is from here):

```
public class RazorContext : DbContext
{
    public RazorContext (DbContextOptions<RazorContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<OutputAccessRights> OutputAccessRights { get; set; }
}
```

2.appSettings.json(here I use the default sql server in visual studio):

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "ConnectionName": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 }
```

3.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{ 
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddDbContext<RazorContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionName")));
}
```

4.Run command line on Package Nuget Manager:

```
PM>add-migration init
PM>update-database
```

5.Then you could set the data:

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorContext _context;

    public EditModel(RazorContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public IList<OutputAccessRights> UsersAccessRights { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        UsersAccessRights = await _context.OutputAccessRights.ToListAsync();//set the data to UsersAccessRights
        return Page();
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IList<OutputAccessRights> usersAccessRights)
    {
        //do your stuff...
    }
}
```